# What's the best way to store my datastructure in database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am building an online shop and I have a problem. 
I will have products which have a direct price (for example HTC Touch 2 Smartphone: $299.00 ), but in the same time I will have products which have prices for combinations based on varieties:
for example:

```
product: Nike Exclusive T-Shirt 2011
varieties: 
   Sizes: L, XL
   Colors: red, blue
combinations will be: 
L white - $10
XL white - $15
L blue - $11
XL blue - $16
```

I need the best way (or the only one working :) ) of database structure, where I can store both types of products, and if I want to list my products from a category which contains both types of products on the webpage (single price, multiple prices) i can build a mysql query to get all the products in the same query.

thanks

UPDATE

I will have for sure the following tables: `[products]`, `[varieties]` (color, size), `[varietyValues]` (which stores what king od colors and what kind of sizes does the product have - each one is a row in the table {productId + varietyId + value (red, S, M, green, XL, etc...)} ). After this one I would have another table `[combinations]`, with a many-to-many [n-to-m] relationship between `[combinations]` and `[varietyValues]` which will result a new table `[combPrices]`. Each row of this new n-to-m table will have a price.

Now the problem is I can't figure out how to store single-price products in this data structure.

---

UPDATE 2

In this image you can see the database diagram, which I think would be ok for the multiple-price products:
[image: database diagram]

THE MAIN PROBLEM:
Since this is a webshop, people will put items in the shopping cart. I think the items inserted into the shopping cart should be from the same table (in our case it would be the `[combinations]` table, since there are the prices stored).

Here are some data for these tables, just to be more clear:

`[products]`

```
productid   |   productName
1           |   Nike T-Shirt
2           |   HTC Touch 2 Smartphone
```

`[specifications]`

```
specId   |   productId   |   specName
1        |   1           |   Size
2        |   1           |   Color
```

`[specvalues]`

```
specValueId   |   specId   |   svValue
1             |   1        |   L
2             |   1        |   XL
3             |   2        |   white
4             |   2        |   blue
5             |   2        |   red
```

`[combinations]` (items into the cart)

```
combinationId   |   price   |   description
1               |   10      |   White L Nike T-Shirt
2               |   15      |   White XL Nike T-Shirt
3               |   11      |   Blue L Nike T-Shirt
4               |   16      |   Blue XL Nike T-Shirt
5               |   18      |   Red XL Nike T-Shirt
```

`[combinationParts]`

```
nmid   |   combinationId   |   specValueId
1      |   1               |   1
2      |   1               |   3
3      |   2               |   2
4      |   2               |   3
5      |   3               |   1
1      |   3               |   4
2      |   4               |   2
3      |   4               |   4
4      |   5               |   2
5      |   5               |   5
```

I hope my diagram and database population does make sense :) .

So the final question is how can I store the single price products (HTC Touch 2 Smartphone) so it can be added to shopping cart just like the multiple price products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily store the price next to the product and use a query like this to get the products.

```
SELECT p.productid, 
       p.productname, 
       CASE 
         WHEN cb.combinationid > 0 THEN cb.price 
         ELSE p.price
       END, 
       cb.combinationid 
FROM   products p 
       LEFT JOIN specifications sp 
         ON sp.productid = p.productid 
       LEFT JOIN specvalues spv 
         ON spv.specid = sp.specid 
       LEFT JOIN combinationparts cbp 
         ON cbp.specvalueid = spv.specvalueid 
       LEFT JOIN combinations cb 
         ON cb.combinationid = cbp.combinationid 
WHERE  p.productid IN ( 1, 2 ) 
       AND CASE 
             WHEN cb.combinationid > 0 THEN cb.combinationid IN ( -100, 1, 2 ) 
             ELSE 1 = 1 
           END
```

this needs as input product numbers and combinations. Since the combinations can be missing, I've added -100 as default value

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just add a nullable price column to your products table ?

If you want to easily access all the prices with a single query, you could use a view :

```
create view combPrices as
select ProductID, null as Variety, Price from tbProducts where Price is not null
union
select tbProductDesc.ProductID, tbProductDesc.Variety, tbProductDesc.Price 
from tbProducts
inner join tbProductDesc on tbProducts.ProductID = tbProductDesc.ProductID
```

Comment: I guess you're saying that I could store the price of the single-price products in the products table, that's ok, but could you tell me what query can read all the products from a category (and all variations in the same time) ?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it seems like you're going to need two tables with a one to many relationship.
Something like: (Psudocode)

```
Products
   ProductID int autoincrement
   ProductName text

ProductDesc
   ProductDescID int autoincrement
   ProductID int foreign_key
   ProductDescription text
   Price float
```

So you would then fill it like:

```
Products
   1 'HTC Touch 2'
   2 'White Shirt'
   3 'Blue Shirt'
   4 'Nike Exclusive T-Shirt 2011'

ProductDesc
   1 1 'Smartphone' 299.00
   2 2 'Large' 10.00
   3 2 'XL' 15.00
   4 3 'Large' 11.00
   5 3 'XL' 16.00
   6 4 'L White' 10.00 
   7 4 'XL White' 15.00
   8 4 'L blue' 11.00
   9 4 'XL blue' 16.00
```

Then it wouldn't matter if a product had one price or many prices.

Comment: More details? What do you need?

Comment: Seems pretty complicated. I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around how it's all supposed to be connected. It looks like you designed it around storing clothing information, and then decided to branch out after that. Its not clear what's supposed to be stored in Combinations, but is there a way to add new types to just make it work? Many to many can also be 1 to 1. Add a new type to Varieties for electronics, etc.  What would you do if a shirt only came in Large Blue? A HTC Touch 2 wouldn't be a whole lot different.

Comment: To be honest, I think your database is a little to normalized. If one of the constraints is that you can't change the structure or constraints, then your only real choice is to cheat a little. [specifications] Insert a new type, say electronics. 3 | 2 | Electronics. [specvalues] insert a line, something like 6 | 3 | Phone. [combinations] Insert 6 | 299 | HTC Touch 2. [combinationParts] 6 | 6 | 6.
Then you wont have to make any real changes to your store. You'll have a phone with one size and price. However, if you can change the structure, I think you can make it a little more friendly.

Comment: Without changing the database structure, this could be useful for electronics with multiple prices, IE, memory. HTC Touch 2 8GB 199, HTC Touch 2 16GB 299, HTC Touch 2 32GB 399. Or whatever. I think that with your current structure you need to treat the phone as if it was a shirt with only one size and color, like if your could only get the nike shirt in the large blue size. That would be a product with one price too.